# Simultaneous scripts: MySQL server unresponsive

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I want run a PHP script that loops through each entry of TableA. It does some web crawling and if a certain condition is met, it INSERTs something into TableB and updates TableA.
While that script is running, I cannot query TableA from other PHP scripts/pages. They are unresponsive until the first script is finished or cancelled.

What can be the problem?

Script 1:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM TableA");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  // do some stuff
  if ($condition) {
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO TableB ...");
    $stmt2->execute([...]);

    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE TableA ...");
    $stmt2->execute([...]);
  }
}
```

Script 2:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ...");
$stmt->execute([...]);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// from here it is not responding while Script 1 is running
```

(LAMP server)

Comment: Most likely the PHP script is producing some kind of lock on the table, but it's difficult to tell without actually seeing the script.

Comment: OK - how and where should I remove the lock? I added some code.

Comment: move away from using `while` and use other method to loop through the data. the script wont be done until the `while` condition is met. if you have thousands of data to loop through, its important create smaller function to manage the data

Comment: like fetchAll()?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by running script 1 from command line on the server instead of browser.

Maybe someone can roughly explain why it's not working when running both scripts in a browser.